# php convert array format to array

Tags: arrays, format

i have a array format in the database and i want to convert it to array() :

```
$productORG = "(
[0] => Array
    (
        [name] => Fashion Style Stand Collar Multi-Zipper Embellished PU Leather Jacket For Men
        [code] => 1
        [qty] => 1
        [price] => 21.54
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [name] => Fashion Style Solid Color Turndown Collar Side Single-Breasted Long Sleeves Woolen Coat For Men
        [code] => 2
        [qty] => 1
        [price] => 2
    )

)";
```

its a some text 
i want to convert to array values .... 
example :

```
   print_r($productORG);
```

thanks

Comment: Why do not use that in normal way? I.e. hold array in your variable from the beginning?

Comment: how ? please help ...